# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: apex, error

I get this error, `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`, when I try to save one of my test classes.

Any idea what it is and how to fix the error?

When I try to save my class in the **Developer's Console**, I get an `Internal Salesforce Error`, and I can't save my test class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These type of errors do not normally surface to Apex developers, aside from what it means in Java context, it basically indicates something internally wrong with the platform and/or the internal state of your classes in the org. Typically you have to raise a case with Salesforce (giving them the numbers included in your Internal Salesforce Error message), which I'd still advise, however here are a few things i would try to unstick things...

- Setup > Apex Test Execution > View History > Clear Test Results
- Setup > Apex Classes > Compile all classes
- Delete the class and add it again
- Switch to another development / sandbox org if you can easily

**Inner Class Thoughts:** I've seen some instability with inner classes in Apex classes in the recent past, as with your experience it comes and goes. However I cannot help feeling it stresses a few things if used aggressively, such as lots of references outside the parent class to inner classes. I'm not saying don't use them, just if you are and you need to do something to stabilise things might want to make some of them parent class for now. For sure though you need to raise this with Salesforce.

Comment: I'm having to delete and recreate my test class almost every time I want to "save".  Though not ideal, your 'delete + recreate' allows me to continue writing code.  =]

Comment: No problem, glad its keeping you moving! Just added a final thought re: inner classes to the answer btw.

Comment: Your thought is intriguing.  The class I'm testing __does__ use a couple of inner classes **very** extensively.  I'll make sure to log a ticket with SF support